# StatusLogger Multiple logging implementations found

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j2, slf4j

In an application using log4j with slf4j, I am trying to use elasticsearch jar which depends on log4j2.

The application's logging dependency looks like this-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

The application is using its own `log4j.xml` and has some custom appenders of log4j so it cannot be migrated to log4j2 without rewriting the appenders.

Added the below dependencies as suggested in elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_using_another_logger.html) for using a different logger other than log4j2.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${es.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>${es.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But now on starting the application, I am seeing some warnings like below

```
DEBUG StatusLogger org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory is not on classpath. Good!
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
WARN StatusLogger Multiple logging implementations found:
Factory: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory, Weighting: 10
Factory: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory, Weighting: 15
Using factory: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory
```

Can someone let me know what does this warning denote? How can I remove it?

Comment: which version of ES you are using

Comment: ES Version - 5.6.16

Comment: can you just exclude the logging dependencies which elasticsearch brings and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in [log4j2 mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/201908.mbox/%3CB677447A-DDBD-4321-A073-4500EB6360C7%40dslextreme.com%3E)

> I think what you are trying to say is
>
> 1. Your app needs to use Log4J 1.x.
> 2. You are trying to include something that is using the Log4J 2 api.
>
> The problem you are encountering is that you have provided 2
> implementations of the Log4J api - log4j-to-slf4j and log4j-core. You
> can only have one of them. You need to exclude the Log4J core jar from
> whatever is declaring it as a dependency.
>
> On another note, converting Log4J 1 appenders to Log4J 2 isn’t
> particularly hard. Log4J 1 hasn’t been maintained in many years and
> was declared end-of-life 4 years ago.
>
> Ralph